# Displaying multiple fields as labels if one field is null in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am having some issues trying to show multiple fields for a single label in QGIS. In QGIS2.6, attempting to display labels for a feature consisting of multiple fields results in an empty label if one of the fields is null. So for example, in the label expression dialog:

```
concat("Temp Site",'\n',"Notes",'\n',"Function")
```

will function normally unless one of the fields is null, then it results in no label being shown. Using the '||' operator instead in the expression dialog also results in the same behaviour:

```
"Temp Site" || '\n'  ||  "Notes" || '\n'  ||  "Function"
```

Is there a way to display the labels even if one of the fields is null?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the "Coalesce" function. Coalesce takes the first non-null value from its arguments. So this expression should work:

```
coalesce("Temp Site",'') || '\n'  ||  coalesce("Notes",'') || '\n'  ||  coalesce("Function",'')
```

Comment: You can also wrap the new line within the coalesce function, if it makes sense to avoid the blank lines in the middle of the label  I used an expression like `coalesce("Temp Site", ' ') || coalesce(('\n' || "Notes"), ' ') || coalesce(('\n' || "Function"), ' ' )`

Answer (score 3):

Update: This is no longer a problem. In QGIS 2.10 and greater Concat ignores null values and coalesce is no longer needed. See this answer instead [Handling NULL values in labeling?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166300/handling-null-values-in-labeling?noredirect=1&lq=1)