# Multi Labelling with missing values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

The code for multi labels eg.:

```
Field1 || '\n' || Field2
```

works fine, unless you have a missing value (`NULL`) in one of your fields, in which case QGIS doesn't show any labels at all (for the specific object).
I use QGIS 3.10.14-A Coruna.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simpler answer using "coalesce" : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122199/displaying-multiple-fields-as-labels-if-one-field-is-null-in-qgis

Answer (score 6):

A very simple way: use `concat()`:

```
concat("Field1", '\n', "Field2")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add an if-condition that evaluates the length of the string: if it is longer than 0, return the string, otherwise (in case of `NULL`) return an empty string: `''` (two single quotes):

```
if (
    length ("Field1"  )>0, 
    "Field1" , 
    ''
) || '\n' || if (
    length ("Field2"  )>0, 
    "Field2" , 
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following. We create an array from our fields, then filter the `NULL` values and finish by concatenating the array with `\n` separator

```
array_to_string(
  array_filter(
    array(Field1,Field2),
    @element IS NOT NULL
  ),
'\n')
```

If you want to treat both `NULL` values and `''` empty string as the same, change the filter expression `@element IS NOT NULL` with `length(@element) > 0` like below

```
array_to_string(
  array_filter(
    array(Field1,Field2),
    length(@element) > 0
  ),
'\n')
```

Both 2 first solutions are fine to REMOVE the `NULL` values. So if first field is empty, first line will contains the 2nd field content. If you want to keep position with an empty string, you can use

```
array_to_string(array(Field1,Field2), '\n', '')
```

PS: maybe "overkill" here because only two fields but with more fields, surely more useful. Comment added after @MrXsquared answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I know that my suggested solution is not the best compared to the simplicity of [@MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/391002/63384) solution, but I am adding it as reference:

```
case 
when "Field1" is null then "Field2"
else "Field1" || '\n' || "Field2"
end
```

If null is in `Field1`, which is the field that contains null values, then show only `Field2`. If both fields have values, then show both `Field1` and `Field2`

Here is aa illustration:

[image]